# How to preview word , excel , pdf local file in angular 7 ,offline?

Tags: angular, angular7

Before upload , **strong text**I want preview office local file in angular 7

Comment: Please improve your question to get answers. It looks something like a dummy text.

Comment: You could try to use the HTML `<object>` element (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)